# Jquery checks var is undefined error SCRIPT5007 in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I get params from td cells in this way (using dataset)

```
var cellsParams = {};
$(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
    cellsParams[i] = this.dataset;
});
```

And I tried to check where params "align" is not undefined.

```
$.each(cellsParams, function(n, params) {
    var cssClass = params.align !== undefined ? 'class=\"' + params.align + '\"' : '';

});
```

With firefox and chrome works well, but whit IE 10 I have this error.
**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'align': object is null or undefined.**

How can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: What happens if you make `cellsParams` an array instead of an object (since you're *using* it as an array, and `each` may not return what you want on an object)? That is, initialize it as `var cellsParams = [];`

Comment: @PaulRoub - Unfortunately raises the same error

Comment: I think the problem is that IE needs a comma at the end of my object. How do I add it? Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How, why, would an object have a comma at all?

Comment: @PaulRoub - obj { a, b, c } IE error, obj {a, b, c,} IE ok.

Comment: (a) IE may *accept* the trailing comma, but if so, it doesn't *need* it (b) that syntax isn't used anywhere up there. What is `this.dataset`, by the way, and how/where is it set?

Comment: dataset - http://html5demos.com/dataset

Comment: In practice, IE fails to control the variable that does not exist, while firefox and chrome.

Comment: Unless you're running IE 11 or above, [IE does not support dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Browser_compatibility). So `params` will always be `undefined`, and the first time you references `params.align`, you're getting exactly the error I'd expect.

Comment: @PaulRoub - I used dataset to store in my object all the properties data- of my element.

Comment: oh sh...t ! I read that ie 10 has partial support !! Thank very much for your time!